# How to test if the voltage in a circuit is a certain amount

Tags: voltage

I recently found out that memory is stored in a computer with  lots of capacitors that hold 0 or 5V. I presume this is how binary would work (so 5V is 1 and 0V is 0). How would I (say) turn on a lightbulb if the voltage is (say) 25V?

Comment: *At least* 25V, or *exactly* 25V?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Dynamic ram is stored in capacitors. Capacitors achieve a good storage density. But they leak, and so dynamic ram has to be refreshed.   DRAM is not the only way of storing data electronically. Static RAM (SRAM) stores data in stable feedback loops formed by transistors. Look up "SR Latch" and "D Flip Flop".  Transistor circuits can exhibit state (thus memory) without capacitance. Once upon a time, magnetic cores were used for memory, which is where we get the computer term "core" (as in "core dump", not "CPU core"!).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams exactly 25V. I was thinking about completing a circuit only when the voltage is a certain value.

Comment: @Kaz Great comment! I upvoted it, and it has certainly made it clear. If only you'd answered with that comment, you would have got much reputation xD

Comment: @imulsion  Since the voltage is exactly 25V only for infinitesimally short times you can just leave the lightbulb dark.  You need to either specify a tolerance band around the 25V, or turn on the light for a specified time after the voltage crosses 25V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olin's transistor circuit is a *standard* way to switch a load from a microcontroller, but it's not a *universal* way. The main limitation is that it only works for DC loads (direct current), and not for AC (alternating current).

[image]

It's not clear where your 25 V comes from. Is that the rated voltage for the bulb, and do you expect that your logic should work at the same voltage to switch it on? In that case it's worth noting that Olin's circuit has two different voltages: a 5 V control voltage, which may come from a microcontroller's output, and a 25 V load voltage. **The two voltages don't have to be related in any way.** With the right transistor type you can switch 1000 V from a 3.3 V microcontroller. What *is* required is that you can connect the two supplies; they should have their respective grounds ties together (the black down arrow in the schematic).

Sometimes you can't do that, for instance because the 25 V (or 1000 V) is directly connected to the mains. You don't want to be electrocuted when you press the microcontroller's button, so you provide isolation between the two voltages. You'll still use the transistor, but that will switch a *relay* instead of the bulb. The relay's contacts are isolated from the activation voltage and you use those contacts to switch the load. This is also a solution if your bulb works on AC instead of DC.

[image]

About the data bit you stored in the capacitor. That's how DRAM (Dynamic RAM) works. But the capacitance is extremely small (otherwise it would need too much real-estate on the IC), and the contents leaks away in milliseconds. That's why DRAM memory has to be refreshed all the time: data is read and rewritten, so that the capacitor's voltage for a "1" stays near the required 5 V. It's not that voltage that can control the transistor either: in between refreshes the microcontroller reads the level (which again discharges the capacitor, so that it has to be rewritten again) and may decide to make an I/O pin high, which controls Olin's 2N4401 transistor. There's a lot of transistors between the stored data bit and the microcontroller's output. And remember that you don't have to work at 25 V to switch a 25 V load. As far as I know there are no microcontrollers working at a voltage higher than 5 V.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an electronics noob and capacitors were the only way I heard of to store memory

Comment: @imulsion - Either you're a noob, *or* you apologize, but not both! :-). The capacitors are quite good, since you only need one transistor per bit -> lots of data on a single chip. The RAM modules in your PC are DRAM. SRAM (Static RAM) needs at least 4 transistors per bit, where basically 2 transistors interlock with each other. This way they keep the data at the desired level until that level is changed from outside the cell; the "1" becomes a "0" and vice versa. Once data is written to the cell that way it will stay like that until power is removed: that's memory.

Answer (score 4):

There are vaious electronic components that can be controlled with low voltages that can switch higher voltages.  Bipolar and FET transistors are probably the most common of these components, but old fashioned mechanical relays can do this too, among others.

Here is a simple example circuit using a NPN transistor as a switch:

[image]

This particular circuit can reliably support about 200 mA of current thru the lightbulb, which means it can be up to a 5 watt lightbulb.  There are many other ways this could be done too.